# Capistrano cannot find SVN client

Tags: capistrano

I have an SVN client locally and on the Solaris production server, and they are in my path, so when I type svn somethng the command is found (my PC and Solaris).

This is the error:

```
C:\dev\apps>cap deploy:migrations
 * executing `deploy:migrations'
 * executing `deploy:update_code'
   executing locally: "svn info https://svn.domain.co.uk/svn/apps  -rHEAD"
 *** executable 'svn' not present or not in $PATH on the local system!
* executing "svn checkout -q  -r6 https://svn.domain.co.uk/svn/apps /sites/r
ails-data/apps/releases/20100120114312 && (echo 6 > /sites/rails-data/apps/relea
ses/20100120114312/REVISION)"
   servers: ["solaris001.ds.domain.com"]
Password:
  [solaris001.ds.domain.com] executing command
** [solaris001.ds.domain.com :: err] ld.so.1: svn: fatal: libaprutil-1.so.
0: open failed: No such file or directory
** [solaris001.ds.domain.com :: err] Killed
   command finished
failed: "sh -c 'svn checkout -q  -r6 https://svn.domain.co.uk/svn/apps /sites/
rails-data/apps/releases/20100120114312 && (echo 6 > /sites/rails-data/apps/rele
ases/20100120114312/REVISION)'" on solaris001.ds.domain.com
```

In my PC and in Solaris I can successfully run the commands that Capistrano is unable it cannot find the library and the executable.

This is my recipe:

```
set :application, "apps"
set :user, 'me'
set :domain,      "solaris001.ds.domain.com"
set :repository,  "https://svn.domain.co.uk/svn/apps"
set :use_sudo,    false
set :deploy_to,   "/sites/rails-data/#{application}"

role :app, domain
role :web, domain

namespace :deploy do
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "touch #{current_release}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  task :stop, :roles => :app do
    # Do nothing.
  end

  desc "Restart Application"
  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    run "touch #{current_release}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution: http://riccardotacconi.blogspot.com/2010/01/rails-deployment-with-capistrano-and.html